# How to create a new column in a dataframe by multiplying another column by a constant?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which includes a column of the prices for plane/train tickets. I was able to convert them to USD, but was not able to create another column which holds the price values in usd.

I used travel.iloc[:, 5] *= 1.11 to multiply each item in the column with the price in euroes by 1.11 (amount of dollars in a euro).

How do I go about making a new column in the dataframe with this information?

Answer (score 1):

```
travel['dollars_in_euro'] = travel['euro_price'] * 1.11
```